# read txt file in android from my mobile device

Tags: android, file

I have 4 txt files in my desktop.
I create an android app where I will read these files and print these in an EditText, but
these files are drug drop in ddms -> myapp -> data -> files.

So with emulator my app play correctly, but in my mobile phone, don't read these files and close the app.

This is my code:

```
    public String ReadFileTrack1()
    {
      FileInputStream fIn = null;
      InputStreamReader isr = null;
      char[] inputBuffer = new char[900];
      String data = null;

      try
      {
         fIn = openFileInput(tracks[0]+".txt");
         isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
         isr.read(inputBuffer);

         data = new String(inputBuffer);
      }   

      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      finally 
      {
         try 
         {
             isr.close();
             fIn.close();
         } 

         catch (IOException e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      return data;
    }
```

The code is correct, but don't play in my mobile phone.
What I can do for this problem?
How can i load these 4 txt files in my mobile phone so that my app play correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to an app's private storage directory on a secured device, unless the application first makes a subdirectory and grants others write access to it (which is generally a bad idea).

Put the files on the external storage (sdcard) instead, or package them as assets in the apk when you build it.

(There is an exception: if the application is built debuggable, then one can use the adb shell's run-as tool to copy something into the private directory as the appliction user, but that's obscure and not something you'd want to use as it does not apply to finalized apps.  Generally that capability is used in the other direction, to examine what an app under development has done to its files or database when it is not working correctly)